# Add columns name to datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
      DataGridView dgv=new DataGridView();
      for(int i=0;i<ivc.Columns.Count-2;i++)
      {
        //MessageBox.Show((ivc.Columns.Count-1).ToString()+"  "+i.ToString());
        dgv.Columns[i].Name=("col"+i).ToString();
      }
```

The value of ivc.Columns.Count is 13.

The error is:Index extened! The index must less than 0,and less than set.Why?The dgv may have no limit index.

My purpose is:
  1.Make the code more simple! 
  2.Init a new DataGridView to store other DataGridView data to global DataGridView.

PS:The primary code is like this:

```
           DataGridView dgv=new DataGridView();          
           dgv.Rows.Clear();
          //dgv.ColumnCount=8;      
          //dgv.Columns[0].Name="col1";
          //dgv.Columns[1].Name="col2";
          //dgv.Columns[2].Name="col3";
          //dgv.Columns[3].Name="col4";
          //dgv.Columns[4].Name="col5";
          //dgv.Columns[5].Name="col6";
          //dgv.Columns[6].Name="col7";
          //dgv.Columns[7].Name="col8";
```

Comment: What do you want, can you say exactly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put following code just before the for loop:

```
dgv.ColumnCount = ivc.Columns.Count-2;
```

Comment: When we create an object of DataGridView, initially it doesn't have any column so if u check dgv.Colums collection it will be empty. Henve before accessing any column first we will have to set the dgv.ColumnCount so that it will add that much number of columns in dgv.Colums collection.  In this way we can access the columns and set its name.

Comment: But sometiems we even don't know how much columns we should add?

Answer (score 0):

Inside loop do like this

```
 dgv.Columns[i].Name= "col" + i.ToString();
```